# Fail2ban - block malicious attack

Tags: apache, fail2ban

I wish to block this zombie IPs from my server(apache) with fail2ban, here the one from access.log

```
184.106.10.130 - - [21/May/2017:10:00:12 +0800] "POST /core/model/modx/error/list.php HTTP/1.0" 404 171 "http://example.com/core/model/modx/error/list.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) U2/1.0.0 UCBrowser/9.3.1.344"
```

I had removed the malicious files, how do I block it with fail2ban rules?

I wish to have the Definition of : POST, all php file & 404

Here is my filter.d/ban.conf:

`failregex = <HOST> .*"POST .*.php.* 404`

---

Appreciated any help, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
failregex = <HOST> .*"POST .*.php.* 404
```

This works!